# PocketVJ change root folder

Tags: php, raspberry-pi3

I have recently been following this tutorial to set a Raspberry Pi up for projection mapping:

https://gist.github.com/baydam/a905e4878f54150f7da421e2c1d17a21

I have gone through the entire process, and is able to access the control panel for the mapper using its IP address. However, one of the final parts of the tutorial leaves me stranded, and after extensive googling, I have not been able to find the solution.

My problem lies with this part:

> install eXtplorer in /var/www/eXtplorer and configure it: sudo nano /var/www/eXtplorer/include/init.php
>
> change the root directory to '/media/';

I don't know excactly how to do that. I can edit the file and - based on google searches - have tried to change the line:

```
$GLOBALS['home_dir'] = !empty( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ) ? $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] : '.';
```

to

```
$GLOBALS['home_dir'] = '/media/';
```

This does not work. eXtplorer still starts up in its own root folder, and I have no way to find the correct folder...

I hope one of you can help me

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found out!! :D

Turns out I did not need to change any code at all. Rather, I could edit the home folder directly in the eXtplorer window.

I tried removing the eXtplorer folder and placing a clean version in its place.

When I first logged on, I used the basic login and pass "admin" (both places). It then warned me to change the password, and in the same window, I was able to define the home folder. Changing this to /media/ did the trick :)

Now I just need to try out whether I did all the rest of the things correctly ;)